# How could a soul be tormented by sulfur fire?

Tags: revelation, death

[Revelation 20:10 (ESV)](http://www.esvbible.org/Revelation%2020%3A10/)

> and the devil who had deceived them was thrown into the lake of fire and sulfur where the beast and the false prophet were, and they will be tormented day and night forever and ever.

Many times in Bible the lake of fire and sulfur has been mentioned. I am wondering: as long as man is in this form of human body, which is ashes and dusts, he will suffer from this fire, but if a man dies, how could his soul have any feeling related to the sulfur and fire?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to Christianity

Answer (score 0):

In his *Dialogue with Trypho the Jew*, St. Justin Martyr wrote that "there are some others, who, having supposed the soul to be immortal and immaterial, believe that though they have committed evil they will not suffer punishment (for that which is immaterial is insensible), and that the soul, in consequence of its immortality, needs nothing from God."<sup>**(1)**</sup>

However, he counters this notion, saying, "'But I do not say, indeed, that all souls die; for that were truly a piece of good fortune to the evil. What then? The souls of the pious remain in a better place, while those of the unjust and wicked are in a worse, waiting for the time of judgment. Thus some which have appeared worthy of God never die; but others are **punished so long as God wills them to exist and to be punished**.'<sup>**(2)**</sup>

Thus, God endows the souls of the wicked with sensibility and punishes them for as long as He wills.

**Footnotes**

<sup>**(1)**</sup> Ch. 1

<sup>**(2)**</sup> Ch. 5

**References**

Justin Martyr. *Dialogue of St. Justin the Philosopher and Martyr with Trypho the Jew* (Τοῦ ἁγίου Ἰουστίνου Φιλοσόφου καὶ Μάρτυρος πρὸς Τρύφωνα Ἰουδαῖον ∆ιάλογος).